# file upload array

Tags: php

when i upload a file before uploading i just print the file array by using print_r($_FILES); it will print following array.

[image] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] =>

> > [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) )

so whats reason besides it that will not give actual file attributes.

Comment: Yeah accept some answers but anyways post some code because if your enctype is ok we need to see some code something is wrong.

Comment: Please provide the code of the upload form, php file.

Answer (score 4):

To the upload form, you must add the enctype `multipart/form-data`

as:

```
<form action="me.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks
yeah i used this  enctype="multipart/form-data" but still same problem

Answer (score 0):

In your form, are you setting the encoding type correctly?

ENCTYPE="MULTIPART/FORM-DATA"

What OS is your server running?

Comment: thanks 
yeah i used this  enctype="multipart/form-data" but still same problem. and
os is windows xp sp-2

Comment: For some reason I have had problems using $_FILES on windows servers.  Google search did not come up with anything.

Have you checked the relevant file-upload settings in your php.ini file?